# How to identify a mobile User in Unity without an explicit registration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First of all, I have been searching forums for about a year for a viable solution. What I am looking for is a way to identify a mobile User by an ID that is NOT linked to the device.

So no `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier`

My thoughts go out towards identifying Users using the Google Account of the User (Android) or the Apple account (iOS).

What I have tried so far is connecting the application through the GooglePlayGames API. It is successfully connected and works fine. It logs in automatically when I start the application and I retrieve and store the googleId in my database.
The drawback here however is that the app is now dependent on GooglePlayGames, which is something I dislike. I don't like explicit dependencies on other apps. And I also need to find a suitable equivalent for iOS.

I have yet to implement the Unity IAP to enable in app purchasing. I could not find any info on how transactions are linked to Users on android/ iOS. Is there a way to retrieve/store any User related Id during transactions?

It seems to me that when working with in app purchasing, that you need to have some way to reimburse/reactivate purchases made by users when they switch phones for example.

Best case scenario would be an easy way to store an Id without depending on Unity IAP, so that Free To Play Users can also easily recover their account.

Comment: Why no `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier`?  *"a way to identify a mobile User by an ID that is NOT linked to the device."* If you need to identify a device, you need something that's lined to the device otherwise the identification will not work properly.

Comment: SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier is not 100% reliable, especially not on IOS. Furthermore I will lose the connection to the User if he switches device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Mac Address. This is unique for every device.

```
string GetMacAddress()
{
    string reesult = "";
    foreach (NetworkInterface ninf in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (ninf.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) continue;
        if (ninf.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            reesult += ninf.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    return reesult;
}
```

Now, if the device is jail-broken or tampered with, the Mac Address can be spoofed or temporary changed.

> SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier is not 100% reliable, especially not
>   on IOS. Furthermore I will lose the connection to the User if he
>   switches device.

You can use Unity's `SocialPlatforms` API to check if the user is logged in then obtain the user id. That you can use to determine the user on any device.

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate(success =>
{
    if (success)
    {
        Debug.Log("Authentication successful");

        string userInfo = Social.localUser.id;

        Debug.Log(userInfo);
    }
    else
        Debug.Log("Authentication failed");
});
```

If you really need more control over your users, you should implement your own token-based authentication such as **oauth2**. It's not really hard to make one yourself if you have background of PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I do use Socialplatforms to authenticate through Google. 
Without attaching Google, the UserId it retrieves is a test id (even on live devices).
I will however look into the token-based authentication, because the sever runs indeed on PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you need to implement the [Apple Game Center](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.GameCenter.GameCenterPlatform.html).

The docs make it look pretty easy, looks like a single function call that will prompt the user to sign in if they're not already signed in.

Should work the same as the Google Play Store API after that.